# Is it always possible to recover from a failed installation of a ROM?

Tags: installation, rom

in the past I changed the ROM from my phone and the installation was correct. Now I'm currently working in a custom ROM, where I'm doing some alterations on Android Source code.
So, my question is: if I flash my phone with my custom ROM e something goes wrong, is it always possible take a stable ROM (that I already have) and install back to my phone? Or my phone can break without having how to recover it?

Once the installation failed on the middle, and I just start it again and everything worked fine, but the ROM were stable and now I'm customizing it. Or even in that time I had luck!

Thank you for now
Pablo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have recovery installed you can flash another ROM, stock or custom. The kernel/boot.img would be dependent on the ROM and they would most likely come with the ROM package. So if you have a ***complete*** ROM, with all necessary parts, you will be able to to recover from a bad flash.

---

> ***Always make a backup/nandroid***